# Sync TFS workitems so same WI is shown in two team projects

Tags: tfs, synchronization, tfs-workitem

Our team has an a TFS project in which we keep all the teams work. Sometimes some from our team are involved in another project that has it's own TFS project. The tasks that the people from our team does on the other project are in their own area.

Is there a tool that would support synchronizing work items between projects and keep all fields the same value except Area and Iteration? Area would be statically mapped to some value and iteration would live it's own live in each project.

We use the same project template for all team projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of commercial tools, most notably TaskTop, to allow you to sync work items between projects. I have seen TaskTop work well in quite a few circumstances.

The TFS Integration Tool is a free tool provided by the TFS product team that can do synchronisation of work items.